# What are the required libraries for solr custom function?

Tags: solr, solr4

Hi I am trying to use solr custom function from the link 
http://www.supermind.org/blog/756/how-to-write-a-custom-solr-functionquery

But what are the required libraries to add in eclipse for clases `ValueSource`, `IndexReader`.

I just added `solr-core-4.10.1.jar` which contains `ValueSourceParser` but what about the other classes?

Please let me know from where to find other class libraries.

Comment: Just include all jars from the dist folder. It will not cause any problem.

Comment: I have added all the file under dist directory,dist/solrj-lib directory,dist/test-framework/lib directory,dist/test-framework/lucene-libs directory. but still it doesn't recoglinze ValueSource

Comment: Refresh the project once. ValueSourceParser abstract class found in solr-core-4.10.1.jar.

Comment: yes ValueSourceParser is there but where is ValueSource, as I google in solr4.7 thi ValueSource class was in lucene-queries-4.7.0.jar . So no in solr4.10 where it is.

Comment: Yes there is no ValueSource class. you may need to include lucene jar it seems. I am not sure about this.

Comment: yes I found these under example/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib